# ¿Como obtener el nombre completo de un proceso?

Tags: c#

tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que necesito obtener el nombre completo de una aplicacion que se esta procesando en el sistema operativo(como sale en el administrador de tareas). el objetivo es si por ejemplo el proceso es el Microsoft Edge, el nombre me salga asi "Microsoft Edge" y no "msedge"

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero me imprimer msedge y o necesito el nombre completo que sale en el administrador de archivos

```
uint Id;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out Id);
var Process = Process.GetProcessById((int)Id);
Console.WriteLine(Process.ProcessName);// imprime msedge
```

Este es el nombre que necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El nombre que me imprime es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, lo que estas tratando de obtener no es la propiedad MainWindowTitle?
En tu caso seria Console.WriteLine(Process.MainWindowTitle).

Comment: @Gonzalo10 hola gonzalo, gracias por responder, no, el main window title no me sirve ya que si estamos en un navegador o bloc de notas, el titulo siempre sale con el nombre de la accion que se hace, por ejemplo Youtube - Inicio Microsoft Edge y lo que necesito es que solo me salga el nombre de la aplicacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estuve buscando por algunos foros y quizás esto te sirva:

```
        var process = Process.GetProcessById(11484); //Obtuve el proceso de Microsoft Edge. Puedes buscar el id en el cmd ejecutando el comando Tasklist
        var AppName = process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
```

Al principio esto no me compilaba porque mi aplicacion esta configurada como 32 bits y no puedo acceder ej a Microsoft Edge porque es de 64 bits.
Lo solucione cambiando la casilla de Compilacion (Propiedades del proyecto) Desmarcando la casilla Preferentemente 32 bits:

[image: Propiedades de Compilación del proyecto]

Podrías verlo un poco mas detallado aquí:
[Ayuda sobre este problema con "Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/es-ES/be279b05-2eea-4587-8c81-976f75f4cb50/ayuda-sobre-este-problema-con-quoticonextractassociatediconquot?forum=vbes)

El resultado que te devuelve es la descripción de la aplicación, que es lo mas cercano al nombre de la aplicación que te muestra el Task Manager/Administrador de tareas. Es Decir esto:

[image: File Description Task Manager]

Espero que esto te sirva, Saludos!